# Installing PGroonga on Windows 10 for PostgreSQL 11

Tags: postgresql-11, postgresql-extensions

PostgreSQL extension Novice here.

So I am trying to install PGroonga on Windows 10 for PostgreSQL 11(already installed)
The instructions it telling me to extract the downloaded PGroonga package. And I need to specify PostgreSQL folder as extract target folder as show below.

If you installed installer version PostgreSQL,

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\%POSTGRESQL_VERSION%

is the extract target folder.

If you installed zip version PostgreSQL,

> %POSTGRESQL_ZIP_EXTRACTED_FOLDER%\pgsql

is the extract target folder.
I installed my PostgreSQL using the installer version however,I am unable to find this folder on my PostgreSQL and therefore can’t install the extension.
Any help will be highly appreciated .
The extracted pGroonga file has bin, etc, include, lib, share folder. While my installed pg11 also has bin etc include init lib and share folder. Extracting this file here will update the files which I think is not good. I have however copied the files to respective folder but I still get an error when.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgroonga;
```

Comment: If you don't have `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL` then apparently you chose to install Postgres into a different folder during installation. Only you know which folder you chose. If you added the folder to the path, you can try `where psql` to find out the installation location

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I do know where my PostgreSQL folder is. I just can’t find %POSTGRESQL_VERSION%

Comment: You know that you need to replace that with the actual version number? As you installed 11, you need to look for `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11`